# vue wrap another component, passing props and events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, wrapper

How can I write my component to wrap another vue component, while my wrapper component get some extra props? My wrapper template component should be:

```
<wrapper-component>
   <v-table></v-table> <!-- pass to v-table all the props beside prop1 and prop2 -->
</wrapper-component>
```

and the wrapper props:

```
props: {
  prop1: String,
  prop2: String
}
```

Here I want to wrap a table component, and pass to the table component all the props and events that were passed to the wrapper, beside two extra props `prop1` and `prop2`. What is the correct way of doing this in vue? 
 And is there a solution for events too?

Comment: This is specifically what [$listeners](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners) and [$props](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-props) are for.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Place the component you wish to wrap into the template of the wrapper component, add `v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"` to that component tag, then add the inner component (and, optionally, `inheritAttrs: false`) to the wrapper component's config object.

Vue's documentation doesn't seem to cover this in a guide or anything, but docs for [$attrs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs), [$listeners](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-listeners), and [inheritAttrs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs) can be found in [Vue's API documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/). Also, a term that may help you when searching for this topic in the future is "[Higher-Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)" (HOC) - which is basically the same as your use of "wrapper component". (This term is how I originally found $attrs)

For example...

```
<!-- WrapperComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div class="wrapper-component">
        <v-table v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"></v-table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Table from './BaseTable'

    export default {
        components: { 'v-table': Table },
        inheritAttrs: false // optional
    }
</script>
```

**Edit**: Alternatively, you may want to use [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) via the [`is` attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/?#is) so you can pass in the component to be wrapped as a prop (closer to the higher-order component idea) instead of it always being the same inner component. For example:

```
<!-- WrapperComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div class="wrapper-component">
        <component :is="wraps" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"></component>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        inheritAttrs: false, // optional
        props: ['wraps']
    }
</script>
```

**Edit 2**: The part of OP's original question that I missed was passing all props EXCEPT one or two. This is handled by explicitly defining the prop on the wrapper. To quote the documentation for `$attrs`:

> Contains parent-scope attribute bindings (except for class and style) that are not recognized (and extracted) as props

For example, `example1` is recognized and extracted as a prop in the snippet below, so it doesn't get included as part of the `$attrs` being passed down.

```js
Vue.component('wrapper-component', { 
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper-component">
        <component :is="wraps" v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"></component>
    </div>
  `,
  // NOTE: "example1" is explicitly defined on wrapper, not passed down to nested component via $attrs
  props: ['wraps', 'example1']
})

Vue.component('posts', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>Posts component</div>
      <div v-text="example1"></div>
      <div v-text="example2"></div>
      <div v-text="example3"></div>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['example1', 'example2', 'example3'],
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <wrapper-component wraps="posts"
      example1="example1"
      example2="example2"
      example3="example3"
    ></wrapper-component>
  `,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , however OP asks how to exclude certain props. For example  say I wrap a date-picker which accepts a v-model and timeZoneProp. My picker-wrapper has two props value(v-model) and  timeZoneProp . Now I want timeZoneProp to be passed fown to the date-picker but I don't want the v-model to be passed as is , because inside the wrapper I do some data transform on the v-model and then inject down to the picker. How to solve such cases ie exclude certain 'props' but pass the rest down using $atts .Thanks in advance

Comment: @SainathS.R Looking back at this answer again, you're absolutely right. I'll update it, thanks!