# vuejs passing method to child dynamically

Tags: vuejs2

I have a 3rd party component `<third-party-component />` which accepts following event:

```
onAdd, onRemove, onUpdate
```

I want to create a wrapper component around it and want to pass these events dynamically so that can handle the response in wrapper component, something like
wrapper.js

```
<template>
    <div class="my-wrapper">
        <third-party-component />
    </div>
<template>
```

using-wrapper.js

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <wrapper @onAdd="add" @onRemove="remove"></wrapper>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        onAdd() {
            console.log('on add in using-wrapper.js');
        },
        onRemove() {
            console.log('on remove in using-wrapper.js');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to pass methods dynamically to child component so that I don't need to define each and every method.

Comment: unfortunately i think you can't do that , even with global bus , you will still need to do something like that ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vue wrap another component, passing props and events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800945/vue-wrap-another-component-passing-props-and-events)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all attributes and listeners by binding them using `v-bind` and `v-on`

You also need to set `inheritAttrs` to false
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs

```
<template>
    <div class="my-wrapper">
        <third-party-component v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners"/>
    </div>
<template>
```

using-wrapper.js

```
<template>
    <div>
        ...
        <wrapper @onAdd="add" @onRemove="remove"></wrapper>
        ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    methods: {
        onAdd() {
            console.log('on add in using-wrapper.js');
        },
        onRemove() {
            console.log('on remove in using-wrapper.js');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well on "wrapper" you will need to create 3 methods that listen and get triggered on "third-party-component".

```
<template>
<div class="my-wrapper">
    <third-party-component @onAdd="wrapperAdd" @onRemove="wrapperRemove" @onUpdate="wrapperUpdate" />
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
   methods:{
     wrapperAdd(){
       this.$emit("onAdd",{obj that will get to the parent});
     }
   }
}
```

I made only 1 method because the other 2 are similar.

Comment: I wouldn't bother creating methods; the whole thing can be inline ~ `@onAdd="$emit('onAdd', ...arguments)"`, etc

Comment: if he need to do there more than emit an event , he will need to do a method and on my personal opinion it is better to have less javascript on template.