# Vue transparently wrap component, modify some props

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue component that's used multiple times with identical props. I'd like to keep the code DRY by always adding these props in a single place.

Example:

```
<wrapped-foo bar=1 />
```

should be extended to

```
<real-foo bar=1 spam=eggs />
```

I'm trying to solve this using a wrapper component that takes the props given, modifies them, and passes them to the wrapped component. There are multiple tutorials on how to do this, e.g.

- [vue wrap another component, passing props and events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50800945/vue-wrap-another-component-passing-props-and-events)
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components

It looks like all of the solutions don't pass at least one of props, `class`, `style`, event listeners, other attributes, etc. to the wrapped component. Is there a solution that keeps all of these intact?

Comment: are you looking for [Vue Guide: mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)?

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks that seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Vue Mixins: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Or simply with inheritance:

Example:

```
const wrappedFoo = Vue.component('real-foo').extend({
  props: {
    spam: ...
  }
})
Vue.component('wrapped-foo', wrappedFoo)
```